# Vim + elm-vim doesn't recognize .elm file

Tags: vim, elm

I just started programming in elm and I'm setting up my configuration with vim but I'm having some trouble.

I have downloaded [elm-vim](https://github.com/ElmCast/elm-vim) but when I create a .elm file I have no syntax highlight, Ale doesn't work (it doesn't show any suggestions/error)...it's like I have no elm plugin installed.

I have the following global elm packages installed:

```
$ npm list -g | grep elm
├─┬ elm@0.19.1-3
├─┬ elm-format@0.8.2
├── elm-oracle@1.1.1
├─┬ elm-test@0.19.1-revision2
│ ├─┬ elmi-to-json@1.3.0
│ ├─┬ node-elm-compiler@5.0.4
│ │ ├─┬ find-elm-dependencies@2.0.2
```

And this is my .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype off
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on

set autoread
au FocusGained,BufEnter * checktime

let mapleader=","

set so=7

set showcmd
set wildmenu
set ruler
set backspace=eol,start,indent

set smartcase
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set lazyredraw
set magic

" number + relative number
set number
set relativenumber

" Always display the status line
set laststatus=2

" swap files with unique names in this directory:
set directory=$HOME/Conf/vim/swp//

" No annoying sound on errors
set noerrorbells
set novisualbell
set t_vb=
set tm=500
set background=dark

syntax enable

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Text, tab and indent related
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Use spaces instead of tabs
set expandtab

" Be smart when using tabs ;)
set smarttab

" 1 tab == 4 spaces
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4

" Linebreak on 500 characters
set lbr
set tw=500

set ai "Auto indent
set si "Smart indent
set wrap "Wrap lines

""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" => Visual mode related
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Visual mode pressing * or # searches for the current selection
" Super useful! From an idea by Michael Naumann
vnoremap <silent> * :<C-u>call VisualSelection('', '')<CR>/<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>
vnoremap <silent> # :<C-u>call VisualSelection('', '')<CR>?<C-R>=@/<CR><CR>


inoremap jj <esc>
nmap ; :

" Smart way to move between windows
map <C-j> <C-W>j
map <C-k> <C-W>k
map <C-h> <C-W>h
map <C-l> <C-W>l

" Copy from vim with CTRL+C
noremap <C-c> "+y

" avoid scanning useless folders
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*/node_modules/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip

function! VisualSelection(direction, extra_filter) range
    let l:saved_reg = @"
    execute "normal! vgvy"

    let l:pattern = escape(@", "\\/.*'$^~[]")
    let l:pattern = substitute(l:pattern, "\n$", "", "")

    if a:direction == 'gv'
        call CmdLine("Ack '" . l:pattern . "' " )
    elseif a:direction == 'replace'
        call CmdLine("%s" . '/'. l:pattern . '/')
    endif

    let @/ = l:pattern
    let @" = l:saved_reg
endfunction

" set the runtime path to include Vundle and initialize
set rtp+=~/Conf/vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim' " required
Plugin 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'maxmellon/vim-jsx-pretty'
Plugin 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
" NERDTree: shortcut for nerdtree toggle
map <F7> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let g:NERDTreeNodeDelimiter = "\u00a0"

" NERDTREE git plugin:
let NERDTreeMinimalUI = 1
let g:NERDTreeIndicatorMapCustom = {
    \ "Modified"  : "✹",
    \ "Staged"    : "✚",
    \ "Untracked" : "✭",
    \ "Renamed"   : "➜",
    \ "Unmerged"  : "═",
    \ "Deleted"   : "✖",
    \ "Dirty"     : "✗",
    \ "Clean"     : "✔︎",
    \ 'Ignored'   : '☒',
    \ "Unknown"   : "?"
    \ }

Plugin 'valloric/youcompleteme'
Plugin 'dense-analysis/ale'
let g:ale_linters = {
\   'javascript': ['prettier', 'eslint']
\}
let g:airline#extensions#ale#enabled = 1

Plugin 'elmcast/elm-vim'

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

au FileType javascript set sw=2 sts=2 et
au FileType html set sw=4 sts=4 et
au FileType css set sw=4 sts=4 et

au FileType *.py
    \ set tabstop=4
    \ set softtabstop=4
    \ set shiftwidth=4
    \ set textwidth=79
    \ set expandtab
    \ set autoindent
    \ set fileformat=unix
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: updated information after the comments:

output of :filetype:

```
filetype detection:ON  plugin:ON  indent:ON
```

output of :scriptnames

```
1: /usr/share/vim/vimrc                                                                                                  
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim81/debian.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syntax.vim
  4: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/syncolor.vim
  6: /usr/share/vim/vim81/filetype.vim
  7: ~/.vimrc
  8: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftoff.vim
  9: /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/nosyntax.vim
 10: ~/Conf/vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle.vim
 11: ~/Conf/vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/autoload/vundle/config.vim
 12: /usr/share/vim/vim81/ftplugin.vim
 13: /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim
 14: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/plugin/airline.vim
 15: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/init.vim
 16: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/parts.vim
 17: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/util.vim
 18: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim
 19: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree.vim
 20: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/path.vim
 21: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_controller.vim
 22: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/menu_item.vim
 23: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/key_map.vim
 24: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/bookmark.vim
 25: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_file_node.vim
 26: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/tree_dir_node.vim
 27: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/opener.vim
 28: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/creator.vim
 29: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/flag_set.vim
 30: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/nerdtree.vim
 31: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/ui.vim
 32: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/event.vim
 33: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/lib/nerdtree/notifier.vim
 34: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim
 35: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/exec_menuitem.vim
 36: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/fs_menu.vim
 37: ~/.vim/bundle/nerdtree/nerdtree_plugin/vcs.vim
 38: ~/.vim/bundle/elm-vim/plugin/elm.vim
 39: ~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme/plugin/youcompleteme.vim
 40: ~/.vim/bundle/ale/plugin/ale.vim
 41: ~/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/events.vim
 42: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
 43: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/gzip.vim
 44: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/logiPat.vim
 45: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/manpager.vim
 46: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/matchparen.vim
 47: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
 48: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/rrhelper.vim
 49: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/spellfile.vim
 50: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
 51: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/tohtml.vim
 52: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
 53: /usr/share/vim/vim81/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
 54: /usr/share/vim/vim81/scripts.vim
 55: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions.vim
 56: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/quickfix.vim
 57: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline.vim
 58: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/netrw.vim
 59: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/term.vim
 60: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/section.vim
 61: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/highlighter.vim
 62: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/vista.vim
 63: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/ale.vim
 64: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/whitespace.vim
 65: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/wordcount.vim
 66: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/keymap.vim
 67: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes/dark.vim
 68: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/themes.vim
 69: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/builder.vim
 70: ~/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/autoload/airline/extensions/default.vim
 71: ~/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale.vim
 72: ~/.vim/bundle/youcompleteme/autoload/youcompleteme.vim
 73: ~/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/engine.vim
 74: ~/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/statusline.vim
 75: ~/.vim/bundle/ale/autoload/ale/cursor.vim
```

Comment: When you open a `*.elm` file... What does `:set ft?` say?

Comment: Add a verbose to that^

Comment: even with verbose the return value is still the same ` filetype=`

Comment: You're getting an empty filetype, so that's the root of the problem... elm-vim ships an ftdetect script though. What does the `:filetype` command return, does it say everything is "ON"? How about `:scriptnames`, does it list the `ftdetect/elm.vim` script? What else does it list? Please post the output of these as edits to the question.

Comment: The output of scriptnames shows you're getting `~/.vim/bundle/elm-vim/plugin/elm.vim` but for some reason you're not getting `~/.vim/bundle/elm-vim/ftdetect/elm.vim` and that's the one that maps `*.elm` to the right FileType... Now *why* you're not getting it, I'm not sure... Let me take a look, see if I find something about ftdetect that could explain it...

Answer (score 5):

TL;DR: Remove these lines from the top of your vimrc file:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

That should solve the problem.

---

The problem you're having is that elm-vim's filetype detection, which associates `filetype=elm` with `*.elm` files, is not being loaded, even though the plug-in itself is successfully being registered.

The filetype detection in Elm is done by the `~/.vim/bundle/elm-vim/ftdetect/elm.vim` script in your setup, but that script is never being loaded.

The `ftdetect` scripts are loaded in Vim as part of execution of `$VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`, which contains [this snippet](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/filetype.vim#L2179-L2181):

```
" Use the filetype detect plugins.  They may overrule any of the previously
" detected filetypes.
runtime! ftdetect/*.vim
```

The `filetype.vim` file is run as part of the `:filetype on` command, so that's what creates all the `autocmd`s for filetype detection.

However, `filetype.vim` also includes [this snippet](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/filetype.vim#L6-L10):

```
" Listen very carefully, I will say this only once
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
let did_load_filetypes = 1
```

This means that this file will be sourced only once when enabling filetype detection. If you want to re-run it, you need to disable it (with `:filetype off`, which runs `$VIMRUNTIME/ftoff.vim`, which unsets the `did_load_filetypes` global variable) and only then re-enable it again.

And that's why Vundle will tell you to run `filetype plugin indent on` right after calling `vundle#end()`, since by then the `'runtimepath'` will have been adjusted to include the plug-in paths and all `ftdetect` directories from the plug-ins will be found. It will also tell you to run `filetype off` before `vundle#begin()` to ensure it's disabled (it's likely that it might have been enabled from `defaults.vim` or the system-wide vimrc file.) See [Vundle's quick start](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim/blob/master/README.md#quick-start), which lists both steps as required.

So, in short, *only* use a `:filetype on` command (or, more specifically, `filetype plugin indent on`) *after* the Vundle plug-in setup is complete. If you also do it before, you're likely to miss the `ftdetect` of your plug-ins, since those scripts will not be sourced.

Comment: Your answer makes sense but still no luck :(. I noticed that if I run the command `set ft=elm` then everything seem to work but still won't recognize the file at the beginning...

Comment: @ste Does running `:filetype off` followed by `:filetype on` fix it? Look at `:scriptnames`, if you see the `ftdetect/elm.vim` listed there, then it should be fixed... Wanna post your updated vimrc somewhere for another look?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @filebrander didn't work for me, so I found another way:

- 1. Create the following folder: `~/.vim/ftdetect/`
- 2. Create the file `elm.vim` inside this folder.

You have to put the following content in it:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.elm set filetype=elm
```

- 3. Restart vim

This will override the default file detection of the `.elm` files

I hope this will work for you !